# Shiny Hide HTML

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to figure out how I can add both text and an image in my Shiny app without having the HTML code appear on my browser tab.

The code I've found that works to place both the image and text is as follows (used in my ui.R script):

```
titlePanel(div("My title here", img(src = "Image.jpeg", height = 80, width = 175, align = "right")))
```

When I use this, the Shiny app loads with the text on the left and image on the right which is the desired outcome; however, when I open in a browser (tested with both Safari and Chrome), my browser's tab reads

```
"<div> My title here <img src = "Image.jpeg" height="80" width="175"..."
```

Is there any way in Shiny to keep both my title and my image in the top, titlePanel, but have the browser's tab show just the title?

Comment: how do you open it in the browser? with the local host address or do you save it as an HTML file?

Comment: I have used 2 methods for opening in the browser. 1) Within RStudio, I have Run App and from the window that opens, clicked "Open in Browser" 2) I have published to shinyapps.io and opened using the link provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `windowTitle` argument of `titlePanel`, to give a title to the tab when the page is open. The default value is `title`, which is why your tab title has the HTML code you use in `titlePanel`, it's being passed as text to the tab title.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(div("My title here", img(src = "Image.jpeg", height = 80, width = 175, align = "right")), 
             windowTitle = "No HTML in Tab Title")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]